# Deal with missing values in ellipsis arguments ... in R

Tags: r, function, arguments, ellipsis, rlang

How do you deal with missing values in the argument `...` of a function?

I have a generic function `foo` that it's boilerplate code I want to share with other functions (`bar` in this case). I would also like to be able to run `bar()` with missing arguments.

The problem is that when I use `list(...)`, missing values throw an error:

```r
foo = function(...){
  list(...)
}

bar = function(name){
  foo(name=name)
}

bar("a")
#> $name
#> [1] "a"
bar()
#> Error in foo(name = name): argument "name" is missing, with no default
```

The problem here is that `list(...)` forces the evaluation of all the arguments and throws an error before I can perform any `missing` test.

I have been looking at [quosores](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/quosure.html) in `rlang`, but `is_missing` and `quo_is_missing` don't seem to work on `...`.

```r
library(rlang)

foo = function(...){
  lapply(rlang::enquos(...), is_missing)
}

bar("a")
#> $name
#> [1] FALSE
bar()
#> $name
#> [1] FALSE

foo = function(...){
  lapply(rlang::enquos(...), quo_is_missing)
}

bar("a")
#> $name
#> [1] FALSE
bar()
#> $name
#> [1] FALSE
```

And `tidy_eval` fails with the same error:

```r
foo = function(...){
  lapply(rlang::enquos(...), eval_tidy)
}

bar("a")
#> $name
#> [1] "a"
bar()
#> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...): argument "name" is missing, with no default
```

### Edit

To clarify, I would like to deal with missing values the way they are dealt with in this example from the [quosore](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/quosure.html) documentation but in `...` and without having to specify a `is_missing` for each argument in `bar`. I have copied below the example from the documentation:

```r
library(rlang)
fn <- function(arg) enquo(arg)
fn()
#> <quosure>
#> expr: ^
#> env:  empty
quo_is_missing(fn())
#> [1] TRUE
```

Comment: What do you want to be returned when you call `bar()` with no arguments? You can set a default value for name: `bar = function(name=NA){foo(name=name)}`.

Comment: name is a required argument with how you have bar defined

Comment: The edit isn't any clearer. What do you want `bar()` to return? Currently you are hard coding a `name=name` parameter in there. You can't pass a missing value `x` to `list(name=x)`. So do you want to have a named parameter or not?

Comment: Hi @MrFlick, I would like to be able to perform run a `is_missing` check on the list of optional arguments `...`. `foo` is a function that contains some common code for functions that have explicit arguments but with different names. Ideally. I would like to be able to check for missing arguments in `foo` rather than in `bar`. Now, `enquo(...)` does create a list without error when some values are missing, but when you check for missing values in the resulting list, `missing` and `quo_is_missing` fail to spot them.

Answer (score 1):

Like comments said - the problem is not with `list(...)` but with `bar(name)`. You defined a function that takes an argument and you call that function without any arguments, hence the error.

If you want to make `bar()` work even when argument `name` is missing you can use `missing()`:

```
bar = function(name){
  if(missing(name)) {
    foo()
  } else {
    foo(name=name)
  }
}
```

And now `bar()` works:

```
> bar()
list()
```

---

After the edit: the problem seems to be that `list(...)` forces `name` to be evaluated and then it sees that `bar()` didn't see any `name`. Maybe capturing the call to the parent function `bar()` makes sense in your case?:

```
foo = function(...) {
  as.list(sys.call(1))[-1]
}

bar = function(name){
  foo(name=name)
}

> bar()
list()

> bar(name="a")
$name
[1] "a"
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I understand you can deal with missing values with `missing`, but that's not what I am asking. I edited the question, I hope the edit clarifies my question.

Comment: I think I more or less see the problem now, wrote an alternative answer below.

Comment: @DuccioA ping, to check if the new proposal is what you were after.

Comment: Thanks for the edit and sorry for the delay, I was wroking on something else and couldn't test the solution. The problem I have with this solution is that if I specify the arguments by position and not by name in `bar`, I lose the argument name, as in: `bar("a")`. I ended up writing a function that iterates through `...` and turns missing values into `NULL` using `tryCatch`. Anyway, thanks for the answer, I understand my question is not very clear in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to deal with my problem. It is not a real solution to the question, more of a workaround. It uses `tryCatch` to turn missing values in `...` into `NULL`. I'll post it here if anyone find it useful.

```r
library(rlang)
ellipsis_to_list = function(...){
  args_names = call_args_names(match.call())
  args_list = list()
  range = 0:...length()
  range = range[-1]
  for(i in seq_along(range)){
    v = tryCatch(...elt(i),
                 error=function(e){
                   if(grepl("missing", e$message)) NULL
                   else stop(e$message)
                 })
    args_list = c(args_list, list(v))
  }
  names(args_list) = args_names
  args_list
}

foo = function(...){
  args_list = ellipsis_to_list(...)
  args_list[ ! sapply(args_list, is.null)]
}

boo = function(name){
  foo(name=name)
}

boo("a")
#> $name
#> [1] "a"
boo()
#> named list()
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>